# "undefined symbol: Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck"

Tags: perl

I get this message when I try to run a Perl script used in a bioinformatic package named DISOPRED3:

```
/usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: /software6/bioinfo/apps/mugqic_space/software/
perl/perl-5.18.2/lib/5.18.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Cwd/Cwd.so:
undefined symbol: Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck
```

I used the exact same script on my local computer and it works. Now I have to work on a super-computer from a distance and that's where I get this message. I checked, and the Perl versions are the same on both computers.

Comment: Looks like an OS vs. compile mismatch.  What does `uname -a`, `/usr/bin/perl -V`, `ldd /software6/bioinfo/apps/mugqic_space/software/
perl/perl-5.18.2/lib/5.18.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Cwd/Cwd.so` and `file /software6/bioinfo/apps/mugqic_space/software/
perl/perl-5.18.2/lib/5.18.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Cwd/Cwd.so` output?

Comment: Install perl in your own home dir. http://weblog.bulknews.net/post/58079418600/plenv-alternative-for-perlbrew

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you have two installs of Perl, the system one (`/usr/bin/perl`), and one in `/software6/bioinfo/apps/mugqic_space/software/perl`, and the former is using files installed by the latter. The former should not have been told to even look at the files installed by the latter.

Comment: Maybe if they add `/software6/bioinfo/apps/mugqic_space/software/perl/perl-5.18.2/bin` in their path before `/usr/bin` it will use the Perl binary that matches their package's libraries.

Comment: So how to fix this?