# Arch Linux Perl. (Data Dumper) undefined symbol Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck

Tags: perl, archlinux

Since a recent update Perl fails to execute most of the scripts on my Arch Linux System.

Most of the time it failes due to a undefined Symbol in the Data::Dumper module. Other times it is because of the Parser.so with the same undefined symbol Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck

Perl v5.22.0
Data::Dumper is up to date (2.154).

Full Error:

```
/usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Data/Dumper/Dumper.so: undefined symbol: Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck
```

I already tried to reinstall the Modules, did not help.

I found this thread:
[Error running Perl script on 2 different computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626245/error-running-perl-script-on-2-different-computers)

They talk about the problems of differen perl versions, which I do not seem to have here.

Any other ideas? (Reinstall the perl as whole looks impossible for from here...)

Thanks

Comment: Did you update the Perl yourself or did it come as part of your Linux distro? I remember a case where a broken Data::Dumper got put into openSUSE.

Comment: There was an update: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?sort=-last_update&q=perl-data-dumper&maintainer=&flagged=

Comment: But they have the latest release, which is from late 2014... https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Data-Dumper. So it must be something else.

Comment: Perl is part of Arch linux.

Everything worked about a week ago, even the DataDumper.  I cannot tell which update cause the problem, as always there was a bunch of perl updates (https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?sort=-last_update&q=perl)

Comment: Nice connected issue: I cannot upgrade all modules with cpan, because it fails with the same issue while upgrading... -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arch Linux recently upgraded from Perl 5.20 to Perl 5.22.  Those are not ABI compatible, so any XS modules installed for Perl 5.20 need to be rebuilt, or you'll get errors like the one you're describing.

Arch's `perl-5.22.0-1` package includes Data::Dumper 2.158.  Since you say you have 2.154, you must have manually installed an upgrade to Data::Dumper for Perl 5.20.  You need to remove that (now obsolete) version.

Does `pacman -Qi perl-data-dumper` report anything?  If it does, you might try `pacman -R perl-data-dumper`.

**Update:** It seems you've been installing modules into your system Perl directories using `cpan`.  That winds up mixing files installed by `pacman` and files installed by `cpan`, which is why it's not recommended.

You should consider installing [CPANPLUS::Dist::Arch](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CPANPLUS-Dist-Arch/lib/CPANPLUS/Dist/Arch.pod) and using [`cpanp`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CPANPLUS/bin/cpanp) instead.  You can do this with:

```
sudo pacman -S perl-cpanplus-dist-arch
setupdistarch
```

After that, installing modules with `cpanp` will build a package file and install it with `pacman`.  You can then use `pacman` to uninstall them.

Comment: error: package 'perl-data-dumper' was not found. I installed everyhing over cpan.  I will try to remove this version. This should then fix my error.

Comment: I could manually delete the Dumper module. After an cpan upgrade everything worked